# ReValidate On DatePicker Select Using Bootstrap Validator

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm currently using Bootstrap Validator to validate my forms.  On one of my forms, I have a datepicker using Datepicker from JQuery (bootstrapvalidator.com/).  The validation I have validates correctly on first form submit; but, if the field is blank on submit (errors) and then someone goes back and selects a valid date it's not revalidating in real-time.  Anyone know how to validate this after date select?

Example HTML

```
<form id='sky-form' action='/'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="inline">Date</label>
        <%= flight.text_field :date, :placeholder => "Date", id: 'start' %>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Datepicker.initDatepicker();
    $('#sky-form').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
            'date': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Date Is Required'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
                        message: 'Must Be A Valid Date'
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Giantsfan542, Did you ever find a fix for this issue?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: My issues we're based around sky-form so I ended up ripping it out and that solved my issue